# How is yolact integrated into YOLOv5 to achieve target segmentation?

Tags: yolov5

I'm learning YOLOv5 7.0 and found that its object segmentation is very powerful, using yolact to achieve object segmentation, but I don't understand how it does it.

I have searched the community and only said that it is realized through the idea of yolact, but it has not been explained in more detail. I want to know more.